# Extract different values from list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

How to extract a list of different values from following list of tuples?

```
tuple = ((("test", 123), ("test", 465), ("test", 8910), ("test2", 123)))
```

I want to get a list like:

```
different_values = ("test", "test2")
```

Now I want to access all values by this "keys" and get them by a list:

```
test_values = (123, 456, 8910)
test2_values = (123)
```

How to do that?

Comment: Why the extra paranthesis around your tuple list? Also there are no lists (as you said) in your example but only tuples.

Comment: Don't use `tuple` as a variable name -- it will shadow the built-in.

Comment: @Nobody, Sorry, was wrong. @ Sven, Thanks for that advice. This was just an example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd transform your data to a dictionary of lists:

```
d = {}
for k, v in tuples:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Now you can access the keys as `d.keys()`, and the list of values for each key `k` as `d[k]`.

(Shortly, someone will step forward and claim a `defaultdict` would be better for this.  Don't listen to them, it simply doesn't matter in this case.)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, Sven, if you don't feel a `defaultdict` would be preferable here, when is it preferable? (I would use one just because it seems more readable to me.)

Comment: @unutbu: For a `defaultdict`, every single key look-up may create a new key.  In this case, you only want to create new keys during the loop given above -- all later look-ups should fail if the key is not present.  So I'd use a `defaultdict` if *all* look-ups are supposed to add non-existent keys, not just some.  Otherwise I prefer to be explicit about look-ups that might change the dictionary.  Another situation where I might consider a `defaultdict` is if the constructor of the default value is expensive.  The above code creates an empty list in every iteration, even if it isn't needed. ...

Comment: ... Due to the overhead of `defaultdict`, this is actually faster than the `defaultdict` version, but if the constructor were more expensive, things might change.

Comment: @SvenMarnach +1: For comments about expensive constructor.