# Searching list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of data like this

```
data = [['A',11],['A',22],['B',14],['C',23],['C',31],['B',12]]
```

I put the unique items in an other list like this:

```
search=[]
for item in data:
    if search.count(item[0]) == 0:
        search.append(item[0])

# search contains ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

How do I search the list `data` with the list `search` and produce output like?

```
['A', [11,22]]
['B', [14,12]]
['C', [23,31]]
```

Comment: Does it have to be lists? Have you considered putting your data into a dictionary?

Comment: Who's giving this down/close votes? It's a reasonable question...

Comment: No it does not have to be a list. But the list `data` will be created from a csv file, so I thought lists would make it easier.

Comment: @tzaman: In what way is this question reasonable? It's asking how to perform a completely basic task, which has been asked many times before.

Comment: In the right column under *Linked* there's a link to [Extract different values from list of tuples](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9226931/1132524), it's not an exact duplicate since that other one have a list of tuples instead of list of list. **The answer is identical** and even from the same user.

Comment: The problem was I searched for `list of lists` and such things for at least couple of hours and went through every single question and tried to apply those solutions, but none of them worked for me. And the link to http://stackoverflow.com/q/9226931/1132524 appeared in the **Linked** section only after Sven has posted the link almost after the time of my accepting his answer. It is certainly not grounds for closure, if the answers were identical. That question involved `tuples` and mine `lists`. It is only a coincidence that the solution was similar and used `dicts`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a dictionary:

```
d = {}
for k, v in data:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
print d
```

prints

```
{'A': [11, 22], 'C': [23, 31], 'B': [14, 12]}
```

You can get a list of all keys with `d.keys()`.

Instead of building the list `data`, it would probably be better to use a dictionary right from the start.

(Someone else will recommend a `defaultdict` for this soon.  I prefer a `dict` in this case, but it doesn't matter too much.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is a `dict` preferable? Is it just a matter of taste?

Comment: In a list, if you have (in your example) `('B', 12)`, you have to search the results list for `'B'`, which is a linear time operation.  Using a dict, its constant time (and the code is cleaner because this is exactly what dicts are for).

Comment: +1 for `setdefault`, which is new to me.  Thanks for exposing that.

Comment: It is not a big deal, but is there any reason why the the keys are stored in order A, C, B? I ask this since B is encountered before C.

Comment: @AaronDufour I understand the *list* vs. dict advantage because dict is O(1). Was just curious about defaultdict vs dict because personally I would use a defaultdict because it seems cleaner.

Comment: @KishorNanda From the docs: "It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value pairs,... in arbitrary order (if you want it sorted, just apply the sorted() function to it)."

Comment: @PraveenGollakota: See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226931/extract-different-values-from-list-of-tuples#comment11619572_9226977).

Answer (score 5):

I'd use a `defaultdict`, like so:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)
for key, val in data:
    dd[key].append(val)

# dd.iteritems() will give you your output.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = [['A',11],['A',22],['B',14],['C',23],['C',31],['B',12]]
d = {}
for k, v in data:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

for item in sorted(d.iteritems()):
    print list(item)
```

prints

```
['A', [11, 22]]
['B', [14, 12]]
['C', [23, 31]]
```

but consider keeping the `d` dictionary:

```
{'A': [11, 22], 'B': [14, 12], 'C': [23, 31]}
```

It will allow you to access the values more easily.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a dict for this task (or an OrderedDict if necessary). Please read the python documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary of key value pairs, where each key is a first element in a tuple in data (you can only have unique keys in a dictionary), and the value is a list of all items that are in tuples with the key.

```
map = {}
for item in data:
  if map.has_key(item[0]):
    map[item[0]].append(item[1])
  else:
    map[item[0]] = []
    map[item[0]].append(item[1])

>>> map
{'A': [11, 22], 'C': [23, 31], 'B': [14, 12]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a comprehension:

```
grouped_data = dict((x[0],list(y[1] for y in data if y[0]==x[0])) for x in data)
```

Note, that unlike other solutions, this one has quadratic complexity, don't use it on very large lists.

Comment: I don't know how to put this politely, so I'm not. Ugly, *ugly* code.

Comment: @lazyr: python might be not the best language for declarative programming, but in general, I prefer declarative style over imperative. Describe what you want, not how you do it.